# Does a reach weapon allow you to threaten squares 10 feet away or not?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, opportunity-attack, reach

In D&D 5e, does a reach weapon allow you to threaten squares up to 10 feet away for the purpose of Opportunity Attacks or does it just allow you to attack squares up to 10 feet away?

There is some confusion because PHB p.147 says that a reach weapon adds 5 feet to your reach *when you attack with it*, which can be interpreted to mean that, if an enemy is 10 feet away on his turn, he isn't actually in your reach (since you aren't attacking with the weapon yet) so you don't get an Opportunity Attack. Is this interpretation correct and you only threaten 5' away, or does a reach weapon always increase your reach for the purpose of threatening distance?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Yes, reach also determines Opportunity attack range.**

> #### Equipment
>
> **Reach (p. 147).** This property also
>   determines your reach for opportunity attacks
>   with a reach weapon.

— PHB Errata

**Supplemental Evidence**

> Most creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus
>   attack targets within 5 feet of them when making a
>   melee attack. Certain creatures (typically those larger
>   than Medium) have melee attacks with a greater reach
>   than 5 feet, as noted in their descriptions. - PHB, p. 195.

Searching through all the creatures in the PHB at no point was Reach 10 ever specified, nor a feature having anything to do with reach. This might be something featured in the DMG or the MM though.

**[Mearls weighs in](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/502099373648384000):**

> **Josh Smith‏** @Rick___Deckard · [20 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/Rick___Deckard/status/502088135980101632)
>
> @mikemearls Rules clarification: Do reach weapons threaten 10 feet for the purposes of triggering opportunity attacks?
>
> ---
>
> **Mike Mearls‏** @mikemearls · [20 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/502099373648384000)
>
> @Rick___Deckard yes

Answer (score 19):

Firstly, there is no concept of "threatening" in D&D 5e; you can make opportunity attacks when a hostile creature moves out of your reach.

As for reach weapons, the [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) for the PHB clears this issue up once and for all:

> This property also
>   determines your reach for opportunity attacks with a reach weapon.

So yes, a reach weapon allows you to make opportunity attacks when a creature 10 feet from you moves away from you.

Answer (score 10):

To quote Joshua Aslan Smith's answer...

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

This seems pretty clear to me.  A creature using a reach weapon has a larger reach than normal *for the purposes of weapon attacks*, which an opportunity attack with a weapon is.  Do recall that you can attack adjacent foes with reach weapons in 5e, so characters with reach weapons no longer get a free attack when a foe moves adjacent to them, since they haven't "left their reach".

The *emphasized portion* of the above paragraph is a reminder that their barehanded reach isn't any longer than normal, since the grapple rules state they work on someone "within your reach" but go on to clarify "using a free hand", so no one can say my interpretation allows ranged grapples.

Comment: Based on this twitter conversation, this is indeed the correct reading of the rules:  https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/502972149175287808

Comment: And this:  https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/502520711395557376

Answer (score 7):

The Following is an analysis based on a strict reading of the rules, and ignoring designer intent and their use of language.  [The lead designer for 5e, Jeremy Crawford, had this to say about Reach weapons](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/502520711395557376):

> **Yan ᵔ.ᵔ‏** @Plaguescarred · [21 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/Plaguescarred/status/502405904802000897)
>
> @JeremyECrawford I notice people have different interpretation, does polearm increase reach always or only when attacking with it?
>
> ---
>
> **Jeremy Crawford‏** @JeremyECrawford · [21 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/502520711395557376)
>
> @Plaguescarred The reach property applies only when you attack with a weapon. Any use beyond that is up to the DM.

### Rules for Opportunity attacks and Reach weapons don't make (narrative?) sense, but they are consistent. Reach is always 5 feet when not actively making an attack, and not the weapon being used.

- As you will see from the rules of the polearm master, the purpose of opportunity attacks is mainly to prevent people from running past you, and not to punish people who flee your engagement with them.

To understand how/why this is the case, we must first work with the assumption that it's possible and logical that a person with a 10 foot reach weapon when they attack, is going to have a reach of 10 feet for the purpose of opportunity attacks.

Let's first be clear about what an opportunity attack in 5e is.  Normally, an opportunity attack is an attack you are able to make when a creature leaves the area you can reach.  It's a penalty for a creature leaving combat without first disengaging.  It is not an attack which demonstrates what area you threaten. That is, if somebody enters your reach, or moves about within your reach, you do not threaten them. Opportunity attacks seem to serve two purposes:

1. It creates a cost by way of the "disengage" action to leave melee combat with someone once it has been initiated. (This is based the application of the rules with 5 foot reach weapons, but not directly stated in the rules)
2. It prevents enemies running right past you to engage with someone else you are defending/blocking. (Page 195 of the players handbook)

   > You can rarely move heedlessly past your foes without putting your self in danger; doin g so provokes an opportunity attack.

However, when using reach weapons, this seemingly falls apart, no matter which way you interpret the rules.

[image: Diagram showing 5-foot and 10-foot reach areas relative to an enemy 5 feet away and an ally 10 feet away]

The blue square with an x is you. The purple square with an x is an ally, and the green square with an x is a medium creature with speed 30. The red square is your 5foot reach, the Orange square is your 10 foot reach.

**Scenario 1: Reach for opportunity attacks is 5 feet.**
In this scenario, you have just finished attacking the green monster. It is now the monster's turn.  You engaged them in melee combat, but he can now step away from you and go off and do something else without any penalty. Purpose 1 of opportunity attacks has been subverted.  It's arguable that this isn't really the purpose of opportunity attacks, but I think it's the basic assumption for most people, and it's consistent with the rules for 5 foot reach weapons.

**Scenario 2: Reach for opportunity attacks is 10 feet.**
In this scenario, you have just finished attacking the green monster. The green monster now wants to go and attack the purple ally since he is an easier target than you to hit. The monster can smoothly walk right past you, without ever *leaving* your 10 foot reach.  This means you can never do an opportunity attack against them.  Purpose 2 of the opportunity attacks has been subverted, as directly stated by the rules.

That is the situation with your run of the mill opportunity attack.  But now let's include the polearm master feat. (Page 168 of the Players Handbook)

> **Polearm Master**
>   *You can keep your enemies at bay with reach weapons. You gain the following benefits:*
>   • When you take the Attack action and attack with only a glaive, halberd, or quarterstaff, you can use a bonus action to make a melee attack with the opposite end of the weapon.
>   The weapon's damage die for this attack is a d4, and the attack deals bludgeoning damage.
>   • While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter your reach.

And now looks more closely at the wording of the opportunity attack rule.

> Page 195 of the Players handbook
>    The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s
>   movement, occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.

If we edit the rule with polearm master in mind it would read as follows:

> The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s
>   movement, occurring right before the creature ***leaves or enters*** your reach.

So now, with this wording, if your reach with the polearm is 10 feet, you can never actually reach the target which you are stopping.  The creature will be 15 feet away from you when you interrupt it's movement before it enters your reach.  However, if your reach is 5 feet, then before it enters your reach the creature is 10 feet away from you. When you attack the creature, your reach now extends to 10 feet, and you and you can hit it.  This would seem to strongly suggest that two important things.

1. **Reach for opportunity attacks is always 5 feet, and not your weapon or attack.**
2. **The purpose of opportunity attacks is ONLY to prevent people from running past you, and not to prevent people from running away from you after being attacked.**

The alternative is assuming that the rules are wrong and lots of errata is needed all over the place to "fix it".

Something else to notice, is that none of the monsters in the DM Basic rules are listed as having a reach of 10, or anything other number.  However, many *attacks* are listed as having a reach of 10. Such as the Adult dragons' bite. (Though the claw attack is listed as having a reach of 5).  In many cases, you can see one attack having a reach of X, while another attack has a reach of y.  The section in the rules which discusses the reach of a creature extending beyond 5 feet is specifically in the "Melee Attacks" section, and not in the other sections which mention reach.

> Most creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them wh en making a melee attack. Certain creatures (typically those larger than Medium ) **have melee attacks** with a greater reach than 5 feet, as noted in their descriptions.

Of course, if your table decides to play things out differently, you may do so, but be consistent if you do.

All that being said, in the end, the intention of the rules is that an Opportunity Attack is an attack and so the reach property applies to the conditions that allow you to attack as well.  As can be seen from [this conversation on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/502972149175287808):

> **Yan ᵔ.ᵔ‏** @Plaguescarred · [22 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/Plaguescarred/status/502951963130990592)
>
> @JeremyECrawford Why distance discrepency OA provoke base on weapon? You said earlier reach weapon dont increase if not attacking? #Confuse
>
> ---
>
> **Jeremy Crawford‏** @JeremyECrawford · [22 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/502972149175287808)
>
> @Plaguescarred Yes, OA (an attack) is based on your reach with the weapon you're using.

For creatures, you will see that different attacks have different reaches, and so an Ancient Red Dragon for example will have one reach domain for it's claws and another for it's bite, giving it a greater "threat area".

> **Michael Amygdalidis‏** @maplealmond · [25 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/maplealmond/status/504083476820140032)
>
> @mikemearls So an Adult Red has claws (5ft) and bite (10ft) and tail (15ft.)  If I run from adjacent, when does he get to OA?
>
> ---
>
> **Mike Mearls‏** @mikemearls · [25 Aug 2014](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/504087146290876416)
>
> @maplealmond none - only if you move away, dragon picks which one to use. claws make most sense.

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to be,

**1: Can I opportunity attack things when they go from 10 to 15 feet?**

And the answer is yes. The errata say so.

> "This property also determines your reach for opportunity attacks with a reach weapon."

**2: Can I still make an attack when something goes from 5 feet to 10 feet?**

The general consensus is no. Because your reach is now 10 feet, and opportunity attacks only trigger,

> "... when a Hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach."

Open and shut, right? No, and I'm about to grognard so hard.

**You have more than one reach.**

> "Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon Attack, you can use an Unarmed Strike: a punch, kick, head--butt, or similar forceful blow."

Your unarmed strikes are not reach weapons, and you don't need a free hand to have the option.

**Opportunity attacks can be made by any melee weapon attack.**

> "To make the opportunity Attack, you use your Reaction to make one melee Attack against the provoking creature."

It doesn't say I have to use my unarmed strike, just because it left my unarmed strike range. It says make a melee attack.

***Does it provoke at 10 feet? Yes. Does it provoke at 5 feet? Yes.***

I guess the new question, sense I craked this open, is, if you're a polearm master, do they provoke going from 10 to 5 feet?

> "While wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter your reach."

I am wielding a polearm. They did enter my reach. As a DM, I'd say no, though I have no real leg to stand on, other than feel.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 1):

An attack of opportunity is an attack and that attack extends it's reach to 10 ft. You only get an attack of opportunity if a foe leaves that 10ft threatened area. The post above is just editing what the book says to make things more confusing than they should be. If you are a polearm master then you get a reaction attack when the foe enters within 10ft of you.

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to RPG.SE! Check out our [tour] for an idea of what we're like. This answer is nice and clear and to the point, but there's one quibble I have to make: there is no "above" or "below" here, because of those sorting buttons at the top of the list of answers, so nobody knows that you mean by "the post above". In general, it's best to not comment on other posts, and just focus on answering the question as best you can.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple at my table.

Scenario: You have a reach weapon and it's your opponent's turn. At what point do you get the Opportunity Attack?

Answer: When the opponent leaves your threatened area.

Problem: You threaten at two levels, 5' away (1 square) and 10' away (2 squares). So, we count both levels separately, but we don't count going further into your reach as provoking. Thankfully you only have one reaction.

Example 1: If an enemy enters your 10' reach and stays 10' away from you, then when they leave your 10' reach by walking away without using disengage, it provokes an opportunity attack.

Example 2: If an enemy enters your 10' reach, and then enters your 5' reach, they don't provoke an opportunity attack as they are going further into the battle.

Example 3: If an enemy has entered your 5' reach and then leave to your 10' they provoke an opportunity attack.

Example 4: If an enemy has entered your 5' reach and provoked an opportunity attack by leaving it and entering your 10' reach. and then they stopped there and later leave your 10' reach they provoke another opportunity attack.

With Polearm Master

They provoke when they enter your 10' area, and again when they enter your 5' area.

With Sentinel

I houseruled that this is actually your reach rather than 5' it adds a huge protective element to using a polearm that I think is generally lacking.

Many RAW (rules as written) seem to weaken reach weapons. They already deal less damage than most 2-handed weapons. They're heavy so cause disadvantage for small characters. You can't use a shield with them unless you're mounted with a lance. So, most abilities that say 5' I changed to within your reach as a house rule. Honestly, it almost never comes up in my games, but it's something I want.

Answer (score -2):

YES, see this link.

I rule personally that if a creature moves from inside your square to outside moving through your space as difficult terrain that you provoke an OA, on this basis and other evidence i rule that 10' to 5' is also leaving a reach and entering another so it also trigger an AO. but moving without changing reaches

https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/10/07/if-a-monster-has-2-different-reaches-when-does-it-get-opportunity-attacks/

Answer (score -3):

It seems like the point of opportunity attacks is to prevent leaving after combat has started. Now if someone is attacking a creature with reach, the only way to suggest leaving combat is moving out of "their" attack reach. But a Red Claw has three different sets of reach. That would imply that if you moved from 5 to 10, you've left one reach and it could choose an opportunity attack. If you moved from 10 to 15, it could also choose an opportunity attack. If you move from 15 out, it could also choose to make an opportunity attack. It only gets one per turn if I'm not mistaken so it's not getting multiple OAs but leaving any of those three distances in one turn would allow it.

So lets look at a polearm. Perhaps it's the same. I know I can attack at 5 feet with halberd. But I also have reach of 5 (threatening 10). So if you leave my area...EITHER at 10 feet or at 5 feet, I should get an opportunity attack. You only get one reaction (right?) so it doesn't matter if you go through both distances in one move (still just one OA).

Instead of punishing players with reach by creating larger areas for an opponent to move around within (green being able to jump around throughout red and yellow)

[image: reach paradox]
<sup>*[Untitled image](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46362) by [GMNoob](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/2064/gmnoob) is licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)*</sup>

It gives you more choices with an OA for the creature moves by you at 5 OR 10 feet (blue can attack once - if green leaves red OR yellow during that round)