# Can Warlock with the Polearm Master and War Caster Feats cast Eldritch Blast as an Opportunity Attack while wearing a shield, RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, warlock, opportunity-attack

I realize there is the RAI note out there that indicates Polearm Master's opportunity attack is only intended to work with the polearm that you're wielding, but some DMs accept the RAW interpretation which allows casting Eldritch Blast as an opportunity attack if the player has both Polearm Master and War Caster feats, AND is wielding a weapon specified in PAM's description.

Polearms are Two-Handed weapons, but that only applies when attacking with it from what I understand. **Does the RAW interpretation of this combo also allow wearing a shield + one handing the polearm at the cost of being unable to attack with said polearm**?

Comment: I'm confused why the question and answers are being downvoted so heavily after the question was answered (or so I thought). Would anyone care to provide constructive criticism of some sort?

Comment: It would help if your question clarified *why* there is a case for them working in such a manner together. Quotes and citations would be very helpful. Saying that an RAI note exists, and then not explaining or referencing it makes it very difficult to  answer properly.

Comment: No RAW tag = RAW not required, common sense allowed, RAW not enforced. Is that intended?!

Comment: @Trish Focus on the content rather than the tags (tags are not supposed to be special “magic signals” for how to answer a question; instead, answers are supposed to be on-topic for the content of the question, and tags are just for helping *sort* and *search* questions by topic). The [[tag:rules-as-written]] tag would seem describe the content here (the issue is encountered only within a strict RAW rules interpretation) and could be added, but there's a 5-tag limit and it would have to replace an existing one. Can you think of which tag could be removed as less needed? (I'm drawing a blank.)

Comment: I'd remove Warlock, it is not really essential to this question, is it?

Comment: actually the question is pretty much "can I use helbard and shield and have an AoO on 10 feet" in the core - all the rest is addition. Also: RAW interpretation is a nogo: either it is RAW or Rules as Interpreted.

Comment: @Trish (I take it you're objecting to my use of the phrase “a strict RAW rules interpretation” there. I use that because the RAW method is still a method of [interpret](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interpret)ing rules, and doesn't have special super-human ability to avoid using human text-to-meaning translation processes, or otherwise avoid involving a human interpreter to extract meaning.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'd get rid of the Warlock and Spells tags, as neither is relevant. RAW though is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### RAW: Yes, that would work!

1. You can wield a two-handed weapon in addition to a shield.

> **Two-Handed.** This weapon requires two hands **when you attack with it**

(PHB p.147, emphasis mine)

So you can *wield* a two-handed weapon correctly, but cannot attack with it, if your other hand is occupied.

> **Shields.** A shield [...] is carried in **one hand**.

(PHB p.133, emphasis mine)

So, you can carry the shield in one hand, while holding your weapon in the other hand.

2. The opportunity attack would be triggered

By your definition, you are wielding a weapon specified in the *Polearm Master* feat. So you would get the opportunity attack, which you cannot perform (due to the shield), but replace by a spell (due to *War Caster*).

3. You could cast eldritch blast

You can cast a spell as an OA using the *War Caster* feat, you have to fulfill the components of the spell. For *Eldritch Blast* those are verbal (no problem) and somatic, which *"you can perform even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands"* (PHB, p.170, War Caster feat). You would also have to target all individual beams at the creature, which triggered the AoO!

**So, all conditions required for this technique are met, but as you said, you wouldn't be able to use your two-handed weapon!**

Unless your two-handed weapon gives you a relevant bonus I would suggest using a *Quarterstaff* or a *magical staff* you might find as your weapon; they fulfill the requirements of *Polearm Master* and you would be able to use them one-handed because Staffs are (unless stated otherwise) quarterstaffs. (DMG, p.140)

Comment: Using a quarterstaff would give disadvantage on the blasts as enemies would be within 5 ft (unless I got a third feat, Crossbow Expert). Using an actual polearm would allow the OA to go off at the 10 ft range. The weapon is not intended to be used in this setup. It's both crunchy and silly, but it's for play in a group of munchkin, RAW-only players.

Comment: That is a good point about the range. But in principle, it would work either way. I'll leave it in my answer. About crunchy and silly setups: Look at it that way, it basically the same as if you would be a mage with a staff. You wouldn't attack anyone with that staff directly even though it is basically a quarterstaff (p.140, DMG) (hence the example). Your glaive/halbert/pike are thematically just longer, unwieldy, non-magical staffs. Btw. by RAW you could use a magical Staff for Polearm Master (they are quarterstaffs).

Comment: Please explain me how you want to properly use a stick carrying a metal tip that has a significant portion of the weapon weight at one end *properly* and have the metal impact the target with one hand. From a physicist and martial artist standpoint, point 1 of this answer is ok: Yes, you can HOLD it, but you can't *use* a polearm (like a helbard) for you don't use it two handed. Because of this you aren't allowed to use the weapon for an AoO (which is an attack, so any action that is an attack as small lettering does not mean the Attack Action!), so point 2 is sadly invalid.

Comment: @Trish you only need two hands when you attack with a two handed weapon. You can wield it in one hand. Since the warlock doesn't attack with the weapon, but with a spell I see no problem here. Whether I personally am able to do it shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @MonopolyLegend You can get the 10' range AND the ability to use the weapon if you A) go with the quarterstaff as Thyzer suggests and B) pick Bugbear as your race.

Comment: @Thyzer You are only wielding something, if you are actually using it. By the definition of the word: "hold and use (a weapon or tool)" A 2-handed weapon *held* in one hand is *not* wielded.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, but not at 10'

[From the SRD (emphasis mine)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties):

> Reach: This weapon adds 5 feet to your reach **when you attack with it**, as well as when determining your reach for **opportunity attacks with it**.

A polearm only grants 10' reach for attacks made *with the weapon*. Since you need both hands to attack with the weapon, you cannot attack with the weapon, and your reach is not 10'. The opportunity attack is not triggered until the creature approaches to within 5' (your natural reach).

Comment: The opportunity attack would be triggered at 10', though. Even if you do not intend/are not able to attack with the polearm. You have to replace it *then* with a spell. War Caster: *"When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack."* You have to replace the AoO with the spell when the AoO is triggered, which would be at 10' for a weapon with reach.

Comment: @Thyzer I disagree. If you can't attack with the weapon, it isn't adding 5' to your reach, even if you are "wielding" it. Consider the situation without War Caster: a creature moves to engage a polearm master wielding a halberd and a shield in melee. If the creature provoked an AoO moving to 10', the player couldn't take that attack, but if it triggers at 5', the player could (though still not with the halberd).

Comment: @Thyzer said another way, the AoO triggers based on your reach with your melee weapon, even if you use a cantrip instead. If you can't attack with your reach weapon, it can't increase your reach.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but as far as I know there is an often referenced huge difference between a lower case *attack* and an uppercase *Attack*. In this circumstance, even if you do not **a**ttack, the *Opportunity **A**ttack*, as a game term, should be triggered at 10'. It increases the range of the *Opportunity Attack* rule, not just for the **a**ttack triggered by this *Opportunity **A**ttack*. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: if you have multiple reaches (i.E. through a reach-weapon and an unarmed attack), [both would trigger an AoO](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47864/attacks-of-opportunity-while-holding-a-reach-and-a-non-reach-weapon). I think this is also applicable to *Polearm Master* AoO.

Comment: @Thyzer You are right that there is a distinction between making an attack and taking an Attack action. It's less clear when referring to opportunity attacks - this does not appear to be consistently capitalized in the text. I see what you are getting at, but I stand by my interpretation of the RAW.

Comment: A late response, but ["opportunity attacks" are consistently not capitalized in the rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks). It's just that the Roll20 Compendium often wrongly capitalizes and links things when it detects that there's another Compendium entry by that name.

Comment: There appears to be some debate on this topic.  Specifically, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142229/can-you-combine-war-caster-whip-and-warlock-features-to-eldritch-blast-enemies/142231#142231 suggests otherwise.  Could you address this?

Comment: @BenBarden in the linked question, there is nothing to prevent the character from making an opportunity attack with the weapon at 10'; the character simply chooses to cast a spell instead with the opportunity action. In this case, the character is physically unable to make an attack with the weapon at 10', so no opportunity attack is triggered until the target crosses the threshold at which the character is capable of making that opportunity attack: 5'.

Answer (score 2):

## It doesn't work

You can *hold* a Halberd in one hand, but you need two to *wield* it.

Polearm Master requires you to *wield* the weapon.

Comment: You can wield the Halbert, too. The only moment you require two hands is the exact moment when you attack. Also this: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/530377218493386753

Comment: @Thyzer Quarterstaff specific answer is quarterstaff specific and doesn't apply to a helbard.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just a Polearm

If you have improved pact weapon and the Polearm is the pact weapon with focus, then I would allow it with war caster and war caster only.  Because you do not need a hand free.

Not having war caster would be a no.

#### With a shield and a Polearm.

Nope, nope nope.  You have to be able to get the Attack of Opportunity and you never get it without two hands on the Polearm.

Comment: RAW nothing stops a polearm held in one hand from triggering an OA, even though you can't meet the requirements to attack with that polearm! This isn't a problem until War Caster says you can replace the (unactionable) OA with a spell attack!  Insanely, this works RAW, but as a player and as a DM, I would agree with your ruling, as long as player-limiting rules are also interpreted considering RAI and a consistent sense of game logic.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason this wouldn't work, however, you would be limited to Verbal only spells as you have no hands available for Somatic and Material/Focus components (except for a cleric with a holy symbol on the shield.

Comment: Doesn't the War Caster feat remove the Somatic component?

Comment: It doesn't remove it, merely says: "You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands."

Comment: So it removes it in everything but name

Comment: No. You cannot perform somatic components if your wrists are bound, but you still could conceivably be holding things. It's a subtle distinction, but it does not remove the component from the spell.