# Do you avoid an opportunity attack if you are still within your own reach?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reach

Let's say that you are wielding a 10' reach weapon, but are engaged at 5' with an enemy who only has 5' reach. Can you stay engaged but move back 5' without triggering an opportunity attack?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg Asking and self-answering is a 100% accepted practice; getting quality information where other people can find it is the solitary goal of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg Yes, I did. I think it's correct and it's kind of a weird effect that I thought would be good for all to know. I also wanted to see if I had missed something and let someone else show me :)

Comment: @T.J.L. sure, I'm just confused as to why. Just answering a common question?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg If the question hasn't already been asked on the Stack, it should be. All the possible question should be here... eventually.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg I was also kind of surprised it wasn't here -and it's not entirely obvious. I could see a case that because you are still actively engaged, you haven't triggered (but the rules do seem clear it's the way I answered)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## No, the Opportunity Attack is still triggered

The PHB (195) is clear on this:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

There are no additional caveats regarding remaining within your own reach and the only requirement is moving out of someone else's reach.

Comment: What happens if you have multiple attacks with different reach?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47864/attacks-of-opportunity-while-holding-a-reach-and-a-non-reach-weapon?rq=1). But in the case of your own triggering, the only important bit is you *leaving* the range of someone else. Your own reach is not applicable.

Comment: Maybe add that being "engaged" isn't a game mechanic in 5e; that's entirely what reach represents.  There's no notion of "moving out of reach but staying engaged", and opportunity attacks aren't defined in terms of "engagement".

Comment: @Marq you're right - i changed the language.