# Does a Stone Giant get an opportunity attack if I move only 5 feet away from it?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, opportunity-attack, reach

The description of [opportunity attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) in the PHB (p. 195) says:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

For a creature who has no melee attacks with only a 5 ft. reach, such as a [Stone Giant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/stone-giant) whose Greatclub attack has a reach of 15 ft., would it get an opportunity attack on me if I move 5 ft. away from a position adjacent to it?

Comment: Related (sort of): "[Can a monster with no melee attack make an Opportunity Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100702)"

Comment: an inverted duplicate https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110835/

Answer (score 11):

### No

The rule states:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

The Giant reach is unknown (see [the related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157510/)), but the one and only melee attack from the stats block has 15 ft reach. **If** we assume its reach is 15 ft, and you are moving just 5 ft away from it, you are not "out of its reach".

### Your DM can say otherwise

D&D 5th edition empowers the DM in ways that 3rd, 3.5, and 4th did not. While [rule zero](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102507/41726) has always applied, 5th edition chooses not to explicitly codify many things. Your DM might state that, regardless of the Giant's size, its unarmed attacks still has 5 ft reach, so it can kick you as an opportunity attack. This "Giant kick" isn't in the stats block though, so the final adjudication is up to the DM.

Comment: @Medix2 I didn't say the unarmed attack was optional, I said its reach is up to the DM

Comment: Still may be good to note that it's not that the GIant has a 15' reach, but that the greatclub attack is 15' and no other range is given.

Comment: I've opened this question: "[How do you to determine the reach of a Monster's unarmed strikes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157510)"