# Do you get an Opportunity Attack with an unarmed strike at 5ft. when holding a 2-handed reach weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reach

A reach weapon adds 5 feet to your reach making it 10 feet.

If you are holding a 2-handed reach weapon (eg a glaive) with 2 hands and someone moves from 5 feet away to 10 feet away do you still get an opportunity attack? Or because you are holding the weapon are you unable to use an unarmed strike for opportunity attacks?

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate here): [When are Opportunity Attacks provoked while holding a reach and a non-reach weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47864/33707) and [Does a reach weapon allow you to threaten squares 10 feet away or not?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46352/33707)

Comment: Are you asking if you get an OA with the reach weapon or the unarmed strike?

Comment: In addition to the above question, do my edits look agreeable to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90890/discussion-between-rubiksmoose-and-nautarch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **Yes**

The *Two-handed* property definition on pg. 147 (after errata 1.0) has the easy answer:

> This property is only relevant when you attack with the weapon, not when you simply hold it.

If you aren't using your two-handed weapon for the OA, you can just make an unarmed punch with one of your hands.

Additionally,

Given the wording of *Opportunity Attacks* on pg. 195:

> ...you use your reaction to one melee attack against the provoking
>   creature.

and the wording of *unarmed strike*:

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use
>   an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful
>   blow (None of which count as weapons).

there isn't anything preventing you from making an unarmed strike while holding your weapon, even if both hands were full.

Answer (score -4):

I would rule that if you end your turn wielding the glaive, then you can only make attacks of opportunity with the glaive. So if an enemy moves out of your reach (10 ft. with the glaive) then you can make an OA.

Comment: Cool. You can improve this post by adding citations to supporting rules, if any. (We encourage [edit]ing any time a post can be refined to be nearer its best version.) Welcome to the site, take a look at the [tour] and [help], and feel free to drop by [the main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) once you've earned your first 20 reputation points.